# TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined in Node.js and puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to filter an array that contains a bunch of urls. I need to return the urls that only contain the word "media-release".
It currently just sends back the error.
Although I tried removing my `package-lock.json`, it still doesn't work.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/media-releases/all');
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('survey-processed');
    const urls = [];

    for (i=0; i<nodeList.length; i++) {
      urls.push(document.getElementsByClassName('survey-processed')[i].href);
    }
    const regex = new RegExp('/media-release\\b', 'g');
    const links = urls.filter(element => element.match(regex));
    return links;
  });
  console.log(data);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

> error
> (node:10208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
> at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:11:50
> at Array.filter ()
> at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:11:24
> at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\Documents\\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:217:19)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)

Comment: have you tried `urls.filter(Boolean).filter(element => element.match(regex));` or maybe `urls.filter(element => element && element.match(regex));`

Comment: Thank you for "Sharing your gift with the world. Who knows how many codes you are saving just by doing so."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting the page, I found some elements with the class `survey-processed` that are not an `a` element (two forms: `form#search-block-form.survey-processed` and `form#views-exposed-form-newsroom-page.survey-processed`).

`form` elements don't have an `href` attribute thus it will be `undefined` and that's what causing the error.

To fix this issue you have to be more specific with selecting the elements, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with this selector `"a.survey-processed"` like so:

```
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("a.survey-processed");  // get only <a> elements that have the classname 'survey-processed'
    const urls = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {                        // for each one of those
        if(/\/media-release\b/.test(nodeList[i].href)) {               // if the 'href' attribute matches the regex (use 'test' here rather than 'match')
            urls.push(nodeList[i].href);                               // push the 'href' attribute to the array
        }
    }

    return urls;
});
```

Also, if you are looking for only urls that contain the phrase `"/media-release"`, you can use CSS's [attribute contains selector `[attribute*=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to further shorten the code like so:

```
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('a.survey-processed[href*="/media-release"]');  // get only <a> elements that have the classname 'survey-processed' and whose 'href' attribute contains the phrase "/media-release"
    return Array.from(nodeList).map(element => element.href);  // convert the NodeList into an array and use 'map' to get the 'href' attributes
});
```

Comment: Awesome. CSS's attribute contains selector!! I didn't see that coming. What a simpler code! Can't say how much I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually return your filtered result directly and check with `.includes()` if it contains media-release

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/media-releases/all");
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return [
      ...document.querySelectorAll(".survey-processed")
    ].filter(({ href }) => href?.includes("media-release"));
  });
  console.log(data);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: `.includes()` and Rest Parameters are great idea! Thank you for helping me out.